# Javascript is causing my page to crash in IE8 but works in chrome, firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a page on my website that uses a lot of javascript. When loading it in firefox, chrome, safari... it loads fine.

But when I try to view the page in Internet Explorer 8 none of the content is loaded and no error message is given.

If I delete all the javascript but leave in the javascrip tags `<script type='text/javascript'> </script>` the page still doesn't load.

But after removing the script tags the page loads, all be it without any javascript and is therefore useless.

The page is part of an jquery tab setup. All the other tabs contain javascript and load fine, it is just this page.

Any ideas on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that is too vague, what are the contents of the script?

Comment: There is no contents in the script. Even with only the script tags and no javascript at all the page fails

Comment: This is the error details i get in IE

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Sun, 13 Feb 2011 23:38:18 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 99650273
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://dev.fis.org.nz/fundernet

Comment: Since you're in ie 8, just open up the dev tools and set javascript to break on error. You're probably calling some object that Ie doesn't have and erroring out. Just let the debugger tell you what and where.

Comment: @user I get the feeling from that line number (99650273) that you haven't eliminated *all* the JavaScript

Comment: Turns out that the page wouldn't load because I had placed the closing div tag before closing off a for loop. Meaning there were multiple closing div tags. All browsers could handle this but IE broke. Which is a good thing I guess because it pointed out my error. Why the page would load without any javascript I'm not sure but that's what misleaded me in thinking that it was a javascript issue

Comment: Duplicate question from same user:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891759/when-loading-a-page-in-internet-explorer-8-having-a-javascript-section-causes-th](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891759/when-loading-a-page-in-internet-explorer-8-having-a-javascript-section-causes-th)

Comment: Do you really have a page with 100 Million lines of javascript?  May I see it?

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of information, this is only a guess but it's one of the most common reasons for scripts to fail in Internet Explore.

Check for a superfluous comma on any object properties or array members, for example

```
var foo = {
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz',  <-- this comma
};
```

This is only a problem for IE. All other browsers can deal with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same Problem. In my case, there was one `</div>` too much before my script tags.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, as pointed out by Phil, it is caused by extra comma in any JSON object or in any array.   look for the "last" element of any array & object you have. :)